# How to solve 503 Error in Typo3 12 backend?

Tags: php, composer-php, typo3, hosting

I have a problem with my hosting. Locally everything works fine. I cloned my website(typo3 12.4.9), installed composer, imported the database and adjusted the php version to the version of the hosting company.
Now I can access my domain in the browser, but get a 503 error in the Typo3 backend. In the frontend I get the following error: 404 Page Not Found The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No site configuration found.

If you require further informations please ask. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: Added the missing db data to the settings.php and added .htaccess in the public directory (https://docs.typo3.org/p/lochmueller/staticfilecache/main/en-us/Configuration/Htaccess.html). Now I get the backend login but I doesnt work and redirects me to "page not found" after submit.
The frontend error is still there. Login via /typo3/install.php still shows the 503 error.

Comment: First, a 503 is a server error, so look into the server logs, there should be a detailed error. Second, no configuration found: have you defined base variants in the site configuration: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/BaseVariants.html

Comment: I didnt define base variants. Just changed the baseUrl in the config.yaml

Comment: did you check the URL if is identical? with www and without www. It is important as well. Either way, you need to redirect the users to the wished format via htaccess. If you want to use www, then redirect every request to www if it doesnt exist and the other way around if you dont want to use www. This will solve at least 1 of your problems

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Composer itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You linked `https://docs.typo3.org/p/lochmueller/staticfilecache/main/en-us/Configuration/Htaccess.html` which only contains `ext:staticfilecache` related htaccess rules.

First, you should use the `shipped` htaccess for the used TYPO3 coreversion in use, for example following for `12.4.9`: https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/v12.4.9/typo3/sysext/install/Resources/Private/FolderStructureTemplateFiles/root-htaccess

If you are using the `ext:staticfilecache` add the mentioned rules in the documentation to the beginning of the TYPO3 core htaccess file - at least before mentioned lines.

```
# If you use the oldschool .htaccess rewrite rules that come with
# the TYPO3 dummy, then the relevant StaticFileCache configuration
# should be inserted in the .htaccess file just before these lines:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```